# @computed method doesn't work in react + mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm new in react and mobx. I'm trying to use @computed method just for the example. I have the checkbox and after I change it, the state(username) changes, but @computed method doesn't invoke. Here is my code:

LoginStore.js:

```
import { computed, observable } from "mobx";

class LoginStore {

  @observable
  username = "Daimon";

  @computed
  get report() {
    return this.username + "12345";
  }

}

var store = new LoginStore;
export default store;
```

Autorization:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

@observer
class Autorization extends Component {
  test = () => {
    this.props.store.username = "krikkk";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <p>{this.props.store.username}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" onChange={this.test}/>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

export default Autorization;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Autorization from './Autorization';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import loginStore from "./stores/LoginStore";

ReactDOM.render(<Autorization store={loginStore}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "autorization",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-react-scripts": "^0.2.2",
    "mobx": "^5.1.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.8",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your @computed method won't be reinvoked after a change to username because the report method itself is not being used in any valid place.

From the official mobx documentation:

> Computed values are automatically derived from your state if any value that affects them changes. Computed values can be optimized away in many cases by MobX as they are assumed to be pure. For example, a computed property won't re-run if none of the data used in the previous computation changed. **Nor will a computed property re-run if is not in use by some other computed property or reaction.** In such cases it will be suspended.

To make a test, on the render of your Authorization component you can change

```
        <p>{this.props.store.username}</p>
```

to

```
        <p>{this.props.store.report}</p>
```